# How to split comma and semicolon separated string into a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have a variable `users` that contains the following string of text where each user is separated by a semicolon and each attribute of each users is separated by a comma:

```
Bob,1234,Bob@example.com;Mark,5678,Mark@example.com
```

How would I split this into a multidimensional array variable `userArray` that looks like this:

```
[
    [Bob,1234,Bob@example.com],
    [Mark,5678,Mark@example.com]
]
```

using JavaScript?

Comment: Use a CSV library.

Comment: Have you tried to [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it?

Comment: Do you mean "Bob,1234,Bob@example.com" to be one entry in the array or three? Use Nenad's answer if you want them as one entry. Use ```x.split(";").map((y) => y.split(","))``` if you want three.

Comment: Three. So one array with two elements, each element having an array with three elements.

Comment: I think Nenad's edited answer is what I need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var str = 'Bob,1234,Bob@example.com;Mark,5678,Mark@example.com';
var result = str.split(';').map(e => e.split(','));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You probably meant `e => e.split(',')`

Comment: What's the point of `return` in a single expression arrow function?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to split is twice. First by `';'`, and then each element of the resulting array by `','`. Something like this:

```
"Bob,1234,Bob@example.com;Mark,5678,Mark@example.com"
    .split(';')
    .map(function(sub) { 
        return sub.split(',') 
    });
```

Just run the above snippet in your browser console, and you'll see:

```
[
  Array[3]0: "Bob"1: "1234"2: "Bob@example.com"length: 3__proto__: Array[0],
  Array[3]0: "Mark"1: "5678"2: "Mark@example.com"length: 3__proto__: Array[0]
]
```

Comment: Looks great, easy to run in the Chrome's debbuger Console tab with the F12 key. Same idea as Nenad so I went with his answer his since I came across it first.

Answer (score 0):

you just do

```js
var users = 'Bob,1234,Bob@example.com;Mark,5678,Mark@example.com';
    var userInfo = users.split(';');
    for (var i = 0, len = userInfo.length; i < len; i++) {
        userInfo[i] = userInfo[i].split(',');
    }
console.log('userInfo', userInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split by semicolon first and then by comma.

```js
var str = 'Bob,1234,Bob@example.com;Mark,5678,Mark@example.com',
    array = str.split(';').map(function (a) { return a.split(','); });

console.log(array);
```

ES6

```js
var str = 'Bob,1234,Bob@example.com;Mark,5678,Mark@example.com',
    array = str.split(';').map(a => a.split(','));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
var string = 'Bob,1234,Bob@example.com;Mark,5678,Mark@example.com';
var users = string.split(';')
for(var user in users)
      arr.push(users[user].split(','));
JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a one liner that puts every elements in an array.

Here is a solution:

```js
b.split(';').map(e => e.split(',')).reduce((acc, cur) => cur.concat(acc), []).filter(e => !!e)
```