# Loop through a text with semicolon and comma using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var s=Stop;5,Service;13,Error;21,LINK DOWN;53,Data Incomplete;2,Replication Off;0,LINK DOWN;53
```

I need to loop in and get:

```
stop 5
Service 13
Error 21
.
.
```

I need to use an array because I have to get the value of stop service to show it on my html.

I have tried this:

```
var rslt = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  rslt[i] = s.substr(i, s.indexOf(','));
}
```

But it does not give me what I want.

Comment: First, your `s` string is not properly declared. You need to put the value in between quotes `var s = "Stop;5;"` ...

Comment: Your `s` declaration is not valid syntax.  Is `s` a String?  Use quotes `"`.

Comment: its result of an ajax call

Comment: Use the answer(s) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/215552), just replace `&` with `,` and `=` with `;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split comma and semicolon separated string into a two dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334141/how-to-split-comma-and-semicolon-separated-string-into-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split by comma and map the splitted values with semicolon.

```js
var s = 'Stop;5,Service;13,Error;21,LINK DOWN;53,Data Incomplete;2,Replication Off;0,LINK DOWN;53',
    values = s.split(',').map(t => t.split(';'));

console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `split` method with `,` as the argument. You don't need any loop for this.

```js
const arr = 'Stop;5,Service;13,Error;21,LINK DOWN;53,Data Incomplete;2,Replication Off;0,LINK DOWN;53'.split(',');
console.log(arr);
```

And if you want to get rid of those semicolons as well then you can do this.

```js
const arr = 'Stop;5,Service;13,Error;21,LINK DOWN;53,Data Incomplete;2,Replication Off;0,LINK DOWN;53'
  .split(',')
  .map(item => item.replace(';', ' '));
  
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the `;` by a space. Then split your string into an array as following :

```
var temp = s.replace(";", " ").split(",");
```

NB : Your variable s is not well declared. Perhaps have I misunderstood the format of your "text".

Answer (score -1):

Try with `replace()` and `split()`:

```js
var s='Stop;5,Service;13,Error;21,LINK DOWN;53,Data Incomplete;2,Replication Off;0,LINK DOWN;53'

s = s.replace(/;/g,' ').split(',');
console.log(s);
```

**OR:** If you want make with nested array:

```js
var s='Stop;5,Service;13,Error;21,LINK DOWN;53,Data Incomplete;2,Replication Off;0,LINK DOWN;53'

s = s.replace(/;/g,' ').split(',').map(i=> i.split(' '));
console.log(s);
```